# Validation rule for minus or dash symbol SQL ms Access

Tags: sql, validation, ms-access

Hello i'm using Microsoft Access and trying to implement a validation rule where you **cannot** insert into database symbol minus or dash ( - ) but everything else is ok. Is this even possible? Thanks

Comment: Into the whole database, all tables and columns? Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Into specific table column. But i came up with a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While editing table column in validation rule just enter

```
Not Like "*[-]*"
```